# How to apply CSS styles based on existence of Browser API feature?

Tags: javascript, css, safari, intersection-observer

I have a page which has the content invisible (opacity = 0) and based on the `isIntersecting` property as the user scrolls down the opacity changes to 1. It's pretty simple and a basic implementation of the IntersectionObserver API.

However I was having some issue with Safari support and maybe there are others like me who are using older browsers. So I used feature detection in the JS file as below

```
if ("IntersectionObserver" in window){
    
    // Javascript here
}
```

And this works fine for the browsers where it was working even earlier. However my CSS still has the opacity as 0 and I need to show that content with opacity as 1 to those browsers who don't support IntersectionObserver..

**How do I do this?**

**In other words, is there a way where I can apply conditions in CSS and even if there is, then how do I take a JS variable into CSS?**

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the default css is `opacity:0` and you want to change that to `opacity:1` if your javascript detects that the browser does not support IntersectionObserver, correct? It is probably not so hard to add an `else` to you javascript above in which you change the css value.

Comment: @Bazzz Thanks for your response.. but i did not understand.. my Js script just adds a `show` class on first condition of a true `isIntersection` and the it runs the `unobserve` method.. so the js doesn't have direct accès to the css styles

Comment: So you are suggesting that in the else i add a `show` class by default?... Sounds logical .. I'll try it but just wanted to confirm if that's the right way.. or is there a simpler/shorter way?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am suggesting. If the browser detects that there is NO support for IntersectionObserver, what else can it do than just adding the `show` class? Otherwise your element will never be visible. 

Answer (score 0):

Intersection Observer isn't supported below iOS 12, so for the older versions you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/intersection-observer, and then no need for additional CSS changing or anything.

Comment: @zeijkoDe thanks for the update.. your suggestion worked for me, but I'd like one piece of advise, if you could.. it's the first time I am using a polyfill, and I was wondering if i use it the way it's suggested (import it and use it) then I am basically using the polyfill EVEN for all the browsers that support IntersectionObserver.. is that right? Then I am not making use of the benefit of the browser API but instead adding to the JS load of my site.. is this a correct assessment? If yes, is there a way where I can use the polyfill only for browsers that don't support IntersectionObserver..

Answer (score 0):

You could set the opacity using a CSS variable and change that in the JS.

```js
if ("IntersectionObserver" in window){
    
    // Javascript here
}
else {
  document.querySelector('.content').style.setProperty('--opacity', 1);
}
```

```css
.content {
  --opacity: 0;
  opacity: var(--opacity);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">some content</div>
```